Missing 'Top users' link when browsing by tag on Stack Overflow
Usually, when I search for questions by tag, for example, java, there used to be a link to Top users. Why is it not showing anymore on Stack Overflow?
By the way, it's been a long time since I last followed changes on Stack Overflow. Is this a new feature?


The change is part of a (very poorly received) tag experiment which Stack Overflow decided to go ahead with, despite the community hating it. Presumably it's not shown because Stack Overflow are "big fans" of "more clicks" equals "better UX"; you now need to go to the Wiki, and then click "more »" under "Top Answerers".

Ah so frustrating, again someone falls over the disappearance of such links but then only calls it "nice" without explaining why it was nice. I'm honestly interested. One thing the maligned experiment has shown me is that people apparently really care about things I personally don't care about at all and I'm trying to figure out if I'm a replicant or not.

In the same vein, it also means the synonyms link is now an extra click away ("go to wiki" -> scroll down to find it on the right side)

@Gimby It’s fascinating how we each value different things. What you might dismiss as trivial can hold meaning to others, even if that meaning isn't immediately articulated. The beauty lies in our diverse perspectives—whether you're a replicant or not.

Now even go to wiki is also removed.
